# Tuning postgresql (for fast reads with django)

Tags: django, performance, postgresql

we have a django & postgresql setup running on ec2. Our application is always writing to the DB in the background - but this is not initiated from user action.

The problem is that when a user does use the system we need to do a great big read, sometimes with full text search,  of  around 20k items. Any tips on tuning for this scenario??

Comment: Post you schema, adding additional indexes / keys is the simplest. By that I mean creating indexes for common filtering fields etc.

Comment: I have successfully improved postgresql performance on EC2 by following some of the tips in this video: http://blip.tv/djangocon/secrets-of-postgresql-performance-5572403 but as j_mcnally says, we need to know more about the queries you are trying to optimize to give concrete advice.

Comment: http://blog.it-agenten.com/2015/04/tuning-django-orm-text-queries/ - I have written down some performance tuning steps especially for Django + Postgres in that blog article.

Answer (score 2):

20k items is not that big a read. :)

On EC2, the main things to do are:

1. Get as much memory as you can rationally afford; EBS performance is terrible, and you want as much cache as you can manage.
2. Make sure your shared_buffers setting is correct; 25% of available RAM is a good starting point.
3. Look at the big read with EXPLAIN ANALYZE to look for opportunities to create indexes (but don't just create indexes without a practical reason; they're expensive if they are not being used for anything).
4. If changing EBS configuration is an option, consider moving to an 8-stripe soft-RAID configuration.